# Regex for URL not working

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex

I found this regex on regexlib:

```
\b([\d\w\.\/\+\-\?\:]*)((ht|f)tp(s|)\:\/\/|[\d\d\d|\d\d]\.[\d\d\d|\d\d]\.|www\.|\.tv|\.ac|\.com|\.edu|\.gov|\.int|\.mil|\.net|\.org|\.biz|\.info|\.name|\.pro|\.museum|\.co)([\d\w\.\/\%\+\-\=\&amp;\?\:\\\&quot;\'\,\|\~\;]*)\b
```

It works fine unless my URL ends with symbols.

Test string:

```
http://localhost/MySite/Default.aspx?dl=TzV+1tS9W13zQX0NBLpQWS3gzszG5g59814C2PCXb0RqECKPsJ0n087YRaQ4w9iFIM86q8jBfQL3KoOkh79yUjSAV1XtJC4oL9sxeTmegFfD+TvbT/AZgCHpBgk1qOILqrILnpVKe/JWq0QISestnbOT/bq1KrTmHIlZVYuYC0jX2aCLYw2pOYV04Di43mMZNFwhL97m30XEBF2zFXTqyR8JYN0mOEdB4bpdN7SmTvwOzk6GE1paaKnGA0SEJA6+cm9azUrpl5/HIBmMt9I0CgRr+AlWZRlsZU1c+6ZUrX0rWWjUeeN5JHlNcHk0TGuMiuyEt5hmfAPXpxATe0fDXw==
```

The regex will catch the URL up to the last 2 equal signs which won't get included.

I've tried a few other regex patterns to no avail. And I've been trying to monkey with this one for about an hour now with no luck. I just don't know regex well enough!

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `[=]*` at the end like

```
\b([\d\w\.\/\+\-\?\:]*)((ht|f)tp(s|)\:\/\/|[\d\d\d|\d\d]\.[\d\d\d|\d\d]\.|www\.|\.tv|\.ac|\.com|\.edu|\.gov|\.int|\.mil|\.net|\.org|\.biz|\.info|\.name|\.pro|\.museum|\.co)([\d\w\.\/\%\+\-\=\&amp;\?\:\\\&quot;\'\,\|\~\;]*)\b[=]*
```

I'm guessing the url contains base 64 data, which might end in multiple `=`. So adding the `[=]*` tells regex to expect 0 or more equal symbols.

Comment: How could the pattern be changed to include any symbol (and not just equal symbol) at the end of the URL?

Comment: I think I got it based on your answer @gaganshera.  Is there a more efficient way than below? `\b([\d\w\.\/\+\-\?\:]*)((ht|f)tp(s|)\:\/\/|[\d\d\d|\d\d]\.[\d\d\d|\d\d]\.|www\.|\.tv|\.ac|\.com|\.edu|\.gov|\.int|\.mil|\.net|\.org|\.biz|\.info|\.name|\.pro|\.museum|\.co)([\d\w\.\/\%\+\-\=\&amp;\?\:\\\&quot;\'\,\|\~\;]*)\b([=,@,+,!,%,&,*,-])*`

Comment: You shouldn't add commas as separators for regex. Also you should escape characters like * etc. Do it like this: `\b([\d\w\.\/\+\-\?\:]*)((ht|f)tp(s|)\:\/\/|[\d\d\d|\d\d]\.[\d\d\d|\d\d]\.|www\.|\.tv|\.ac|\.com|\.edu|\.gov|\.int|\.mil|\.net|\.org|\.biz|\.info|\.name|\.pro|\.museum|\.co)([\d\w\.\/\%\+\-\=\&amp;\?\:\\\&quot;\'\,\|\~\;]*)\b([=@+!%&\*,-])*`